# Is emasculated a sexist word?

Tags: meaning, gender

The dictionary definition of emasculated is "(of a man) deprived of his male role or identity." or "made weaker or less effective"

So, I'm a guy, and I'm not entirely sure what it means to be deprived of a man's role or identity. Does it mean to not feel manly? Does this word have to do with gender norms? The reason I thought the word was sexist is because it says "man's role".

I found a sentence example saying, "He was worried his pink pants would emasculate him a bit, but he wore them anyway." See it seems like it's talking about gender roles.

Comment: What do the dictionaries tell you about the meanings of the word?

Comment: If you have seen this word in context, what was the context?  A good dictionary will also give example sentences.  These can illustrate how the word is used in context. I'm not sure that a word can be sexist by itself. But it may be used in a sexist way.

Comment: I didn't realize that the definition of the meanings of words depended on one's sex.

Comment: If you are a man, saying that a woman is 'emasculating' you when she speaks up or demands equality is definitely sexist.

Comment: @Lambie I don't see anyone suggesting that.

Comment: @TypeIA Emasculated means deprived of a man's role or identity. The OP says he is a guy. Ergo, his misunderstanding has to do with the fact he is a guy, according to him.

Comment: @Lambie Your words, not OP's, and I don't draw that inference from what he did say.

Comment: @TypeIA No, it's there in black and white. The question has four close votes, fyi. Personally, I don't care one way or the other but people need to take responsibility for their own words.

Comment: @Lambie - what exactly _is_ a 'man's role and identity'? Isn't the very idea sexist?

Comment: @Lambie I agree with the close votes (indeed I cast one myself). I don't agree the OP made any claim that "the definition ... depended on one's sex." It's not "there in black and white."

Comment: It's like saying: I'm a woman with blonde hair and don't get what a bimbo is. [ha ha ha. By the way, heading you off at the pass, I'm a woman and I have blond hair].

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I mean I just read google’s definition. I found a sentence example saying, "He was worried his pink pants would emasculate him a bit, but he wore them anyway." See it seems like it's talking about gender roles.

Comment: @TypeIA sorry for the late response. was my question offensive? sorry, I was just trying understand the definition. It just seemed offensive.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hey Michael, the reason I thought the word was sexist is because it says man's role. Maybe I used the wrong word, and it should have been gender roles. I just found it somewhat offensive.

Comment: @Lambie hey, how's it going? I'm a bit confused. I never said the definition depended on the gender.

Comment: @JamesK I first saw the word used with a women in the context. Maybe sexist isn't the right word. Gender norms? The word seemed outdated for a lack of better words.

Comment: If saying that using the expression "a man's role" is sexist, we might as well just go home. The Brits call this type of question: taking the piss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sexist, no.  Relating to gender norms, most definitely.  That doesn't make the word inherently bad though.  Rather than referring to odd example sentences, let's take a real-world use case. [A few months back, the Welsh standup comic Rhod Gilbert spoke about how he felt emasculated by his infertility](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0955w4j)

It's easy to understand what he meant: his inability to be a (biological) father made him feel less of a man.  There is no assertion, or implication, that in order to be a man, you have to be, or at least be capable of becoming, a biological father.  Just that that's how the experience led him to feel about himself.  The word "emasculated" is usefully describing his emotions there, but I don't think anyone could reasonably claim that he's using it in a way that is sexist, or that is taking any particular stance about gender roles, other than honestly reflecting his emotional responses that are shaped by them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You cleared up a lot of the confusion I had about the word.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of “emasculated” is castrated, although that’s no longer a polite way to refer to someone.  Figuratively, you’re right: it means that a man has lost his male role, or been disempowered.

What is or isn’t sexist in what context is a complicated question, but I’d avoid calling someone else “emasculated” or “emasculating.”  It would be taken as an insult.  The examples you give of polite usage are variations on, “He himself felt less masculine, but he shouldn’t have worried.”